# Serialize Objects of type "Entity" in CRM Online Plugin

Tags: c#, serialization, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

The problem I am trying to solve is that, I need to serialize the Entity's Target/Pre/Post-Image into a json string. I know that we cannot include nuget libraries in the plugins as ILmerge is not an option. This is the one i have tried:

```
var jStr = Serialize((Entity)excutionContext.InputParameters["Target"]);

public static string Serialize<TEntity>(TEntity dataObject)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
         var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TEntity));
         serializer.WriteObject(stream, dataObject);
         return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
    }
}
```

But i am getting the following exception and unable to figure out what i do to solve the same:

System.Security.SecurityException: 'The data contract type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' cannot be serialized in partial trust because the member 'key' is not public.'

Comment: Do you need legit JSON, or are you just using it for displaying it the JSON in the log?

Comment: @Daryl - Yes i need a legit JSON, as i need to pass off those images into their respective systems which can understand and process those further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know we cannot serialize Entity in CRM.

At best you can create a datacontract class with it's get set members and then serialize Entity. But again this will be lot of manual work.

Look into below 2 threads wich gives more info about your issue.

[Thread 1](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/nishantranaweblog/posts/the-data-contract-type-cannot-be-serialized-in-partial-trust-because-the-member-is-not-public-while-using-serialization-in-the-sandboxed-plugin-in-crm-2011)

[Thread 2](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d0332c9c-3cef-4b34-8c11-2b263369e21f/serializing-entity-in-sandbox-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Source.DLaB.Xrm library from NuGet, it contains a SerializableEntity class that was designed to allow for Xml Serialization in sandbox plugins.  You should be able to use it for your JSON here as well:

```
Serialize(new Source.DLaB.Xrm.Sandbox.Serialization.SerializableEntity(yourSdkEntity))
```

The Source.DLaB.Xrm package is a source only NuGet package, so you don't have to ILMerge anything.

Comment: Thanks will try this out and revert asap.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response again, i was trying the above out. I still get the following error: Type 'Source.DLaB.Xrm.Sandbox.Serialization.SerializableEntityReference' with data contract name 'EntityReference:http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the serializer.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried adding the known types as well but at the end, i end up with the same exception.

Comment: Hmm.  You're not passing those entities to the platform are you?  Just trying to serialize them to a string in your plugin correct?

Comment: Code - 
```C#
var knownTypes = new List<Type> {
                    typeof(SerializableEntity),
                    typeof(SerializableEntityReference),
                    typeof(SerializableEntityCollection),
                    typeof(SerializableRelatedEntityCollection),
                    typeof(List<KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>),
                    typeof(List<KeyValuePairOfstringstring>),
                    typeof(List<KeyValuePairOfRelationshipEntityCollectionX_PsK4FkN>)
                };
```
I have added this to the known types on the serializer.

Comment: My objective is to just get those images, serialize those and send those off. Should not have any processing on the entity between, getting and sending.